# $4^x \equiv 1 \pmod{105 }$. Find the smallest integer $x$ and verify that $x$ divides 105

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Through trial and error I found that the smallest integer for $x$ is 6

$4^6 = 4096 \equiv 1 \pmod{105}$.

I'm just not sure if there's a better way to work out the answer.

Also, it may be an error in the question, but obviously when $x=6$ then $x$ does not divide 105.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Edit: Is there a better way to solve for $x$ or is this fine?

Comment: Perhaps it was meant that you verify $105$ divides $4^x-1$?

Comment: Or that $x$ divides $\varphi(105)$?

Comment: $\varphi(105)=\varphi(5\cdot3\cdot7)=(5-1)(3-1)(7-1)$.

Comment: 6 is certainly the smallest *positive* integer which satisfies the congruence which can be seen on http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%5En-floor%284%5En%2F105%29*105+for+n%3D1+to+10 . We can all see that 6 doesn't divide 105. It seems to me that you need to get some clarification on what the question actually is.

Comment: I'm really not sure what was meant, $x$ divides $\phi(105)$ seems likely though, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must have 
$$
4^x \equiv 1 \mod 3, 5 , 7
$$
any power of $4$ is congruent to $1$ mod 3. any even power is congruent to $1$ mod 5, and any power which is a multiple of 3 is congruent to $1$ mod 7. so you need an even multiple of $3$

Answer (score 0):

If you note that $105 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ you are looking for the smallest $x$ such tha $4^x\equiv 1 \pmod 3,4^x\equiv 1 \pmod 5,4^x\equiv 1 \pmod 7$  This becomes $1^x\equiv 1 \pmod 3, -1^x\equiv 1 \pmod 5, 4^x \equiv 1 \pmod 7$  The first we can ignore, the second says $x$ is even, and we know from Fermat's little theorem that $x=6$ will solve the third. We only have to check the divisors of $6$, discovering that neither works and we are done.

Comment: Neither works?  $4^x=2^{2x}$, so by Fermat's little theorem, $4^3=2^6\equiv1\pmod7$

Comment: @Mike:  I meant neither works all the way.  Yes, $3$ works $\pmod 7$, but it is not even, so fails $\pmod 5$